# Cannot use User as User because the name is already in use laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication

when i do registration any user on hosting or live server it show error message

> Cannot use User as User because the name is already in use

but when i do it by localhost it's working fine.

here is a error message

[image]

Comment: can you please add relevant code here

Comment: please show your source code

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you have 2 User model that is being used.

```
use App\User;
use App\User; 

class UserController extends Controller {

}
```

it should be

```
use App\User; 

class UserController extends Controller {

}
```

Comment: use App\User; use only 1 and it's working by locahost with fine